# Вывод названия ярлыка программы

Tags: python

у меня есть некая программа, вводом которой является либо число 1, либо 2. возможно ли как то сделать ярлыки на рабочий стол, при нажатии на который, программа запускалась, и ввод был равен к примеру названию ярлыка?

Comment: А что вам мешает открыть свойства ярлыка и в поле объект после полного пути до программы дописать аргументы, а в программе обрабатывать не ввод, а аргументы командной строки?

Comment: давайте своим вопросам адекватные названия. при чем здесь автозапуск?